# return an entire row of a multidimensional array in VBA to a one dimensional array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array, assign

Is there any way to return the value of an entire row of a multidimensional array to a one dimensional array In VBA?

Something like,  `arr_1dim = arr_2dim(3,:)` is a matlab expression for assigning the row 3 of `arr_2dim` array to `arr_1dim` in one single stretch.

Is there any similar less expensive method in Excel VBA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I slice an array in Excel VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175170/how-do-i-slice-an-array-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No there is no VBA-function to get a row or column. You can only write it yourself, or take a look here:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm

Comment: Specifically, `GetRow` (to get `arr(0)`) / `GetColumn` (to get `arr(1..n,0)`)

Comment: I benchmarked this GetRow (simplest loop approach) against the most voted solution (Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(array, rowyouwant, 0)) and this was 6x faster.

Answer (score 31):

There is a simple way to get a column or a row of a two-dimensional array. Assign a zero to column to get the row, or assign a zero to row to get the column, thus:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(array, 0, columnyouwant) /* or */
Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(array, rowyouwant, 0)
```

See here: 
[How do I slice an array in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175170/how-do-i-slice-an-array-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 4):

This is what I do to easily print out one dimension of a multidimensional array.

Basically, I define a new, 1D array and stuff it with the values from the bigger array.

Example (3D to 1D to Printout):

```
Sub PrintItOut()
     ReDim big_array(10,5,n) as Variant, small_array(n) as Variant

     'use multidimensional array


     'place multi-dimensional values into the 1D array

     For i = 0 to n
            small_array(i) = big_array(0, 0, i)
     Next

     Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, n + 1)) = small_array
End Sub
```

That's how I do it. I hope that makes sense to whoever may be reading it. I think it's a very simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is such an awesome application to work when it comes to matrices, arrays, vectors... ;) But Excel is not that bad, it too is matrix based.

So Assuming you do not want to loop through. You may simply ouput your `multi-D array` into a worksheet using `Transpose` function.

Then pull a `Row` to your desired range size into an array using `Transpose`.

```
Dim vArr as Variant

'--output multi-D array into worksheet
Sheets(2).Range("E2").Resize(UBound(multiDArray) + 1, _
UBound(Application.Transpose(multiDArray))) = multiDArray

'--pull back the row you need: we double transpose here to get 1D. Coz single transpose
'-- results in 2D array..
vArr = WorksheetFunctions.Transpose( _ 
       WorksheetFunctions.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("A2:G2").Value))
```

To be absolutely dynamic, you may `resize` your `range A2:G2` with a dynamic row count using the multi-D `array row upperbound` :)

Comment: @Surya please take a look at the edit. Initial version will only give you a 2D array for `single row-multi column transpose`. You need to do a double transpose in that case ;) I could give you the code, but I want you to have some fun writing the code. Please try out and comment. Happy to help you if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had this question by myself recently, I want to share my code. I wrote a ready-to-use function where you can choose if you want a column or a row to be extracted:

```
'*** Modul 1, define function ***

Function getOneLine(array2D As Variant, lineIndex As Integer, choice As String) As Variant
' returning one column or row of a 2D array
' array2D: 2 dimensional Array
' lineIndex: the index of column or row, starting at 0
' choice: "c" for column or "r" for row

    Dim i, n As Integer
    Dim oneLine As Variant


    If choice = "c" Then

    n = UBound(array2D, 2)
    ReDim oneLine(n)

        For i = 0 To n
            oneLine(i) = array2D(lineIndex, i)
        Next

    getOneLine = oneLine

    End If


    If choice = "r" Then

    n = UBound(array2D, 1)
    ReDim oneLine(n)

        For i = 0 To n
            oneLine(i) = array2D(i, lineIndex)
        Next

    getOneLine = oneLine

    End If

End Function


'*** Modul 2, call function ***

Sub SomeProcess()
    ' Creating a 3x2 Matrix
    ' (In VBA-arrays the column is indexed before the rows
    '  starting at 0. So 3x2 looks like 1x2)
    Dim SomeArray(1, 2) As Variant
        SomeArray(0, 0) = 1
        SomeArray(0, 1) = 2
        SomeArray(0, 2) = 3
        SomeArray(1, 0) = 4
        SomeArray(1, 1) = 5
        SomeArray(1, 2) = 6

    Dim oneLine As Variant
        oneLine = getOneLine(SomeArray, 1, "c")

    Debug.Print oneLine(2)
        ' prints 6

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do something close:

```
ReDim TwoDim(10) As Variant
TwoDim(2) = Array("a", "b")
Debug.Print TwoDim(2)(1) 'Shows "a"
Debug.Print Join(TwoDim(2), "") 'Shows "ab"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Rafael! Your answer is innovative in the use of Join, however, it does not do what the question asks "Return an entire row to a ONE DIMENSIONAL ARRAY", instead it returns a string. If you want to share your knowledge you can create questions with self answeres in SO.