# How to assign part of an array to another shorter array in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

i have a larger array of about 8 elements. I want to assign it to another smaller array of 3 elements. How do i do this? This is my code, but i keep getting an error, "Cant assign to array"
Thanks for your help.

```
Dim largeArr() as variant
largeArr = Array(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)

Dim smallArr(3) As Variant

smallArr=largeArr()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To subset an array, you could feed the small array with individual values of the large one by looping through the desired section.

```
Sub test()
Dim largeArr(), smallArr(1 To 3) As Variant

largeArr = Array(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)

For x = 1 To 3
  smallArr(x) = largeArr(x + 5)
  Debug.Print smallArr(x) 'Print small array in the Immediate Window
Next x

End Sub
```

In the loop, adjust the `i` in `largeArr(x+i)` to reach the desired section of the large array.

See also [How do I slice an array in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175170/how-do-i-slice-an-array-in-excel-vba) .