# How to paste part of two dimensional array into worksheet range without using loop?

Tags: vba

How to paste part of two dimensional array into worksheet range **without using loop** ?
Pasting whole array is straightforward :

```
Sub TestPasteArrayIntoRange()

    Dim MyArray As Variant

    MyArray = [{1,2;3,4;5,101}]

    selection.Resize(UBound(MyArray, 1), UBound(MyArray, 2)) = MyArray

End Sub
```

But what about pasting only second row (first row we could past in by simple reducing selection size to one row) ? I've seen answer for case of one dimensional array which use `Index` Excel function, but it doesn't apply here.

My first idea was to copy array into range and then copy row from it, but it seems, that I cannot create range object which is not part of some worksheet object (expecially cannot create virtual range without virtual worksheet).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175170/how-do-i-slice-an-array-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 1):

I think you will just have to create another function like e.g. GetRow() or GetColumn() to return a reduced vector (or array) with the select values you need. There are some functions here that you can use for your purpose: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm