# How to get address, Column Name and Row Name of all marked rows in Excel table as rows in new worksheet

Tags: excel

I need the row/column combinations marked with an '**`X`**' in my table to be available as three columns in another sheet.

[image: Table 1]

- The first column will consist of the **cell address**,
- the second column will have the **Row Name**, and
- the third column will have the **Column name** of the marked cells.

`VLookUp` and `Index`/`Match` are not helping.

Expected result:

[image: Output]

Comment: What do you mean by row name? Is there a row column with values to the left you want to retrieve? Can you show expected output for given input?

Comment: I have provided a sample expected output of the table I provided. I am trying to get three columns, first with the cell address, the second with the header of the column (top value) and the third with the header of the row (left most value in the row).

Comment: @UshamanSarkar Is there always only going to be 6 rows and 3 columns?

Answer (score 1):

You might get away with something as lazy as, you would change the sheets and the target range srcSht.Range("A1:C5") as appropriate:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook

Dim srcSht As Worksheet
Dim destSht As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set srcSht = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set destSht = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim targetRange As Range

Set targetRange = srcSht.Range("A1:C5")

Dim loopArray()
loopArray = targetRange.Value2

Dim currRow As Long
Dim currCol As Long
Dim counter As Long

For currRow = LBound(loopArray, 1) To UBound(loopArray, 1)

    For currCol = LBound(loopArray, 2) To UBound(loopArray, 2)

        If LCase$(loopArray(currRow, currCol) )= "x" Then
            counter = counter + 1
            destSht.Cells(counter, 1) = targetRange.Cells(currRow, currCol).Address
            destSht.Cells(counter, 2) = "Column " & targetRange.Cells(currRow, currCol).Column
             destSht.Cells(counter, 3) = "Row " & targetRange.Cells(currRow, currCol).Row

        End If

   Next currCol

Next currRow


End Sub
```

Comment: heyy Qharr - I was brainstorming for a worksheet-based solution...  I can create a list of `1` to { `COUNTIF($B$2:$D$7,"X")` } no problem, but do you know of a built-in function that returns the cell of the  th occurence of a value within a range?  (like `Match` but with an *occurence* paramter?)  I've had a few times that could've been handy.

Comment: @ashleedawg Isn't that rather like subsetting an array which I failed on before when we had the co-ordinates exercise?

Comment: @ qharr - your comment triggered an idea, so I've been messing with array formulas for the last hour (again) and I'm **so** close (yet *so* far)...   frustrating, I give up (again!)

Comment: I assumed your code worked?  Or you're also just looking for a worksheet alternative?

Comment: My code works for me though that is often a far cry for working for others!

Comment: I wasn't sure if the OP required a worksheet formula or not (I see he hasn't been back)...   I can get a 1D array of the cell's with X's... I can get a 1D array of all the cell `ADDRESS` in the 2D range...  I can get an sorted array of row or column numbers with values (but can't combine them into an `ADDRESS`)...

Comment: I guess this is the closest:   `=IFERROR(ADDRESS(INDEX(IF($B$2:$D$7<>"",ROW($B$2:$D$7)),ROW()),INDEX(IF($B$2:$D$7<>"",COLUMN($B$2:$D$7)),ROW())),"")` Place in row 1 somewhere, enter as {array} formula.  Row# is the result #. So it "works" but is only looking at column B (ignoring C&D) and also returns the blanks still.

Comment: I wasn't gonna try VBA until you mentioned yours not working (btw it works fine! +1)   Mine's the same idea except uses `<>""` instead of `="x"` since you know some user will get the case wrong (lol), and a little easier thank your nested `For..Next`s is to just do a *`For each cell in range`* and let Excel figure out where they are.

Comment: I will have a further look at your formula but I am guessing it is the usual problem... you can't subset the array? This is where python is soooooo much cooler.

Comment: related?: [Slice array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/175170/8112776) ; [Slice Excel Array](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2010/how-to-access-subset-of-an-array-in-excel-vba/c74765e5-b57e-423f-b9d4-0935ef9674e3) ; [Slice array without loop](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/) ; [Extract subset](https://excelvbaproducts.com/extract-subset-of-an-array/)

Comment: Will look tomorrow but we have a formula answer below......but I guess you realise I mean with formula not with index on array etc. Situation I got stuck on with coordinates question you got right.

Comment: Yeah I'll be looking at it further too.  I'm tempted to throw my own bounty on here...  There's *gotta* be a way.

Answer (score 1):

This array formula seems to be working for me

```
=IFERROR(ADDRESS(SMALL(IF($A$1:$C$6="X",ROW($A$1:$C$6)*100+COLUMN($A$1:$C$6)),ROW())/100,MOD(SMALL(IF($A$1:$C$6="X",ROW($A$1:$C$6)*100+COLUMN($A$1:$C$6)),ROW()),100)),"")
```

but I think could be done more tidily with AGGREGATE.

Also there's no particular reason for multiplying by 100, multiplying by the exact number of columns in the array plus 1 would be better.

Here it is with AGGREGATE

```
=IFERROR(ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$1:$C$6)*100+COLUMN($A$1:$C$6))/($A$1:$C$6="X"),ROW())/100,MOD(AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$1:$C$6)*100+COLUMN($A$1:$C$6))/($A$1:$C$6="X"),ROW()),100)),"")
```

[image]

EDIT

Here is a more general solution for a 2d range of any size anywhere on the sheet.

For the row:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,((ROW($B$2:$D$7)-ROW($B$2))*COLUMNS($B$2:$D$7)+COLUMN($B$2:$D$7)-COLUMN($B$2))/($B$2:$D$7="X"),ROW())/COLUMNS($B$2:$D$7)+1),"")
```

For the column:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MOD(AGGREGATE(15,6,((ROW($B$2:$D$7)-ROW($B$2))*COLUMNS($B$2:$D$7)+COLUMN($B$2:$D$7)-COLUMN($B$2))/($B$2:$D$7="X"),ROW()),COLUMNS($B$2:$D$7))+1),"")
```

For the cell address:

```
=IFERROR(ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15,6,((ROW($B$2:$D$7)-ROW($B$2))*COLUMNS($B$2:$D$7)+COLUMN($B$2:$D$7)-COLUMN($B$2))/($B$2:$D$7="X"),ROW())/COLUMNS($B$2:$D$7)+ROW($B$2),
MOD(AGGREGATE(15,6,((ROW($B$2:$D$7)-ROW($B$2))*COLUMNS($B$2:$D$7)+COLUMN($B$2:$D$7)-COLUMN($B$2))/($B$2:$D$7="X"),ROW()),COLUMNS($B$2:$D$7))+COLUMN($B$2)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar way to get a similar result:

```
Sub listCells()
    Dim rIn As Range, c As Range, rOut As Range
    Set rIn = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:D7")  'input range
    Set rOut = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1") 'first cell for output

    For Each c In rIn
        If c <> "" Then 'not blank so populate output
            Range(rOut, rOut.Offset(, 2)) = Array(c.Address, c.Column - 1, c.Row - 1)
            Set rOut = rOut.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```