# defining array from worksheet not working in filter () lines with type mismatch error

Tags: arrays, vba, autofilter

I'm using secondarray as range of cells in a worksheet (Ex. "1", "2") to exclude them as autofilter list that I'm defining in the below function in "filtercriteria".

I get "type mismatch" error in the filter (secondarray) line for some reason, but I works flawlessly when I define an array using a list of items instead. For example, if I use below line to define secondarray instead.

```
secondarray = ("1", "2")
```

I've researched similar postings and wasn't lucky, can someone help with this instance?

Thanks,

```
Dim secondArray As Variant

secondArray = Range("L76:M76").Value

   c = 0
    k = 0
    count = 0
rowNumb = Worksheets("List").Range(Worksheets("List").Range("L5"), Worksheets("List").Range("L5").End(xlDown)).Rows.count

For L = 1 To rowNumb
    c = Worksheets("List").Range("L5").Offset(L)
    If c <> k Then
        'check the current activity type against the array of types we don’t want. If it isn’t in the array we add it to an array that will be used as the filter criteria
        If UBound(Filter(secondArray, c)) = -1 Then
            ReDim Preserve filterCriteria(0 To count)
            filterCriteria(count) = c
            count = count + 1
        End If

        k = c
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because [filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/filter-function) function takes a One-dimensional array of strings to be searched for its sourcearray   argument.

When you read in a range from the sheet you automatically get a 2d array as opposed to the 1D you have when assigning from a list.

Find a way to use a 1D array to pass in

For example, as your data is coming from 1 row then slice the array by row

```
UBound(Filter(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(secondArray, 1, 0), c)) = -1
```

You may need to find the right method for you.

Another method is given [here](http://vbapacesetter.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/filter-function-for-2-dimensional-array.html).

Comment: Note there are some size limitations on using Index to slice arrays. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175170/how-do-i-slice-an-array-in-excel-vba