# How to find a value in an array?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array:-
Dim arr(0 To 5, 1 To 2) As Variant

I am able to find the minimum value in the array using:-

Debug.Print Application.Min(arr)

How do I find the values that are populated adjacent to the minimum value?

Comment: The same way you would with 5x2 cells or 2x5 cells on the worksheet.

Comment: @Jeeped I am confused! The position of the minimum value changes so I do not know how extract the positions adjacent.

Comment: @Jeeped I tried this:- p = Application.Match(Application.Min(arr), arr, 0)
     Debug.Print p   To find the position of the minimum value but this gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is logic for one way ( note I am reading the array in from the sheet rather than having it already specified).

I loop columns as there are less columns than rows. I seed an initial valid minimum value by taking column 1 minimum `Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, 1))` . I set this value to that of a future column minimum if that future minimum is less than the existing.

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Index` is used to [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175170/how-do-i-slice-an-array-in-excel-vba) the array. By specifying 
Index(array,0,1) I am slicing column wise as opposed to Index(array,1,0) which would be row wise. There are limitations on the array dimensions that will be handled by Index.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetMinumum()

Dim arr()

arr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

Dim currColumn As Long

Dim currMinimum As Double

'set starting value for comparison
currMinimum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, 1))

For currColumn = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, currColumn)) < currMinimum Then

      currMinimum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, currColumn))

    End If

Next currColumn

Debug.Print currMinimum

End Sub
```

Output is -3

[image: Data]

Version 2 to get adjacent value

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetMinumum()

    Dim arr()

    arr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

    Dim currRow As Long

    Dim currMinimum As Double
    currMinimum = arr(1, 1)
    Dim outputValue As Variant
    outputValue = vbNullString

    For currRow = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

        If arr(currRow, 1) < currMinimum Then
            currMinimum = arr(currRow, 1)
            outputValue = arr(currRow, 2)
        End If
    Next currRow

    Debug.Print outputValue

End Sub
```

Comment: appreciate your help but your answer is too complex for me! Not sure that I understand it. I am a newbie. I am able to find the minimum value in my array which in your example would be -3 but I want to how, once I have found the minimum value, to return the value associated with it in Col B. In your example it is 8.

Comment: See my edit version 2. You have an array in which you loop the arr(currRow,1) which is the each row column 1 (i.e. A) and you find the minimum and retrieve the second column , arr(currRow,2) , value to get what is in column B

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I have now had my aha moment and have got it. you are a scholar and a gentleman.