# Code checking/helping

Tags: vba, excel

can someone please look into my code and say me where is the mistake cause I got a type mismatch error message ? With this code I would like to delete all rows who which contain "0" in the respective cells.

I got the error message for the line where is standing: `sn = Application.Index(sn, Application.Transpose(Split(Mid(c00, 2), "|")), [transpose(row(1:8))])` 
Also I had to declare the variable "c00" and I choosed "c00 As Variant". I don't know if it its correct. I would appreciate someone helping me to solve the problem.

```
Dim sn As Variant, c00 As Variant

   sn = Sheets(1).UsedRange

   For j = 1 To UBound(sn)
     If sn(j, 4) & sn(j, 5) & sn(j, 6) & sn(j, 7) & sn(j, 8) & sn(j, 9) = "000000" Then c00 = c00 & "|" & j
   Next

     If c00 <> "" Then
        sn = Application.Index(sn, Application.Transpose(Split(Mid(c00, 2), "|")), [transpose(row(1:8))])
            Sheets(1).UsedRange.ClearContents
            Sheets(1).Cells(1).Resize(UBound(sn), UBound(sn, 2)) = sn
     End If
```

---

**Original Code**

```
Dim LR%


LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 

Set Myrange = Range("D2:AO" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) 'nur Leerzellen
Myrange.Formula = "0"


ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

lastrow3 = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1

    For j = lastrow3 To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(j, 4) = 0 And Cells(j, 5) = 0 And Cells(j, 6) = 0 And Cells(j, 7) = 0 And Cells(j, 8) = 0 And Cells(j, 9) = 0) Then
            Rows(j).Delete
        End If
    Next j
```

---

**Image w/ Error**

[image]

Comment: There is an "upvote" arrow just to the left of a comment, if you hover your mouse over a comment. Such upvotes don't appear in any statistics, or give points, though.

Comment: @CindyMeister Although I believe that the upvoting may require some minimum reputation to do....

Comment: @Mistella Yes, that's possible...

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you, but there is no vote sign shown, only for the other answers/questions.

Comment: @Bamane I just edited my answer to include the final conclusion and link. You can upvote that, or accept it, if you believe it answers your question pretty well.

Comment: @Bamane I also believe that we should clean up this Q&A a bit; so I've suggested an edit to your question with the pertinent information from your "answers".

Comment: @Mistella Thanks a lot for your support. I'll try my best to understand the processes here.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: the error was from attempting to use `Application.Index` on an array larger than the function size limit. Redirect to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24843721/9259306) for Q&A an on alternative option to `Application.Index`.*

---

I'll break down my analysis of your code:

> Application.Index(Array, Row_Number, Column_Number)

The code you currently have:

```
sn = Application.Index(sn, Application.Transpose(Split(Mid(c00, 2), "|")), [transpose(row(1:8))])
```

is saying that the parameters are:

- Array: `sn`
- Row_Number: `Application.Transpose(Split(Mid(c00, 2), "|"))`
- Column_Number: `[transpose(row(1:8))]`

The `Array` section looks fine to me. The Row numbers will, I think(?), be the values for `j` which you collected in `c00` (although the `Application.Transpose` may not be necessary  *Correction: it is in this scenario.*). I have no idea what is going on with your `Column_Number` parameter....

---

**Issues:**

`Application.Index` *keeps* the selected columns/rows. However, your if statement selects the values of `j` where the rows are entirely `0`, so instead of losing them, you would be keeping **only** those rows.

If your intention is to keep all the columns, you can just input `0` into the Column_Number parameter. *Correction: this works when only selecting a single row to keep. If selecting multiple rows, all columns must be listed as well.*

---

**Corrected code:**

Since this code does delete data, you should save a copy of the data before running this code on it.

*Note: `c00` can be a Variant; String also works. You will need to also copy over the `fillA` function, as well.*

```
Dim sn As Variant, c00 As String

   sn = Sheets(1).UsedRange

   ' Changed condition based on your post with previous code. (And negated)
   For j = 1 To UBound(sn)
     If Not ((Cells(j, 4) = 0 And Cells(j, 5) = 0 And Cells(j, 6) = 0 And Cells(j, 7) = 0 And Cells(j, 8) = 0 And Cells(j, 9) = 0)) Then c00 = c00 & "|" & j
   Next

     If c00 <> "" Then
        ' Corrected inputs for Application.Index, Added helper function "fillA".
        sn = Application.Index(sn, Application.Transpose(Split(Mid(c00, 2), "|")), fillA(1, UBound(sn, 2) - LBound(sn, 2) + 1))
            Sheets(1).UsedRange.ClearContents
            Sheets(1).Cells(1).Resize(UBound(sn), UBound(sn, 2)) = sn
     End If
```

---

```
Function fillA(min As Long, max As Long) As Variant
    Dim var() As Variant, i As Long
    ReDim var(1 To max - min + 1)

    For i = min To max
        var(i) = i + min - 1
    Next i
    fillA = var
End Function
```

**Edit:**

Realized this did not address your issue. I suspect that the error was from the `[transpose(row(1:8))]` you were inserting for the `Column_Number` parameter.
Maybe someone else has a simpler way of doing what I did with the `fillA` function (what I believe you were attempting).