# VBA Array Wrong Number of Dimensions

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I am trying to store a list from a multi dimensional array in a dictionary using VBA.

The second last line gives a wrong dimension error. I know the keyArray is 2 dimensions but I want to store the first item in keyArray which is a list then so on.

keys is an array which stores the primary keys from my table there isn't any issues with that.

```
For I = 0 To 15
    'Data which should be going in for that key
    If I < 8 Then
        keyArray(I, 0) = dptData(I)
    Else
        keyArray(I, 0) = data2(I - 8)
    End If
        keyArray(I, 1) = keys(I, 0)
        keyArray(I, 2) = keys(I, 1)
        keyArray(I, 3) = keys(I, 2)

        dict.Add keys(I, 0) & " " & keys(I, 1) & " " & keys(I, 2), keyArray(I)
Next I
```

Comment: KeyArray() is two dimensions, you're only specifying one in the dict.Add line.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to slice an array. Would you like to write a function that takes a multi-dimensional array and a dimension index, and returns a 1D array? `</clippy>`

Comment: [This should be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/175170/1188513)

Comment: I'm unclear why you didn't include the declaration or redim of keyArray.

Comment: Where is keys coming from? Shouldn't those be keyArray?

Comment: A dictionary has a Keys reserved word. Using that reserved word as the name of another array only confuses matters and could potentially lead to conflicts.

Comment: @Jeeped it's a member of the `Dictionary` class. If every member of every object in every referenced type library is forbidden to use for anything, we're all in trouble! ;-) ...that said, `keys` is indeed a confusing name to use for a 2D array, as is `keyArray`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - perhaps but just because you can doesn't mean you should. Here I only see it confusing natters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omitting a subscript from a 2D array doesn't automatically slice it into a 1D array. Use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24843721/1188513) if you need complete efficiency and a function that can be used outside of Excel. [This function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175178/1188513) uses the `Index` worksheet function to perform the slicing, so won't work outside of Excel (and is less efficient, too).

Say you named your function `Slice`, this should do it (assuming `keyArray` is 0-based):

```
dict.Add keys(I, 0) & " " & keys(I, 1) & " " & keys(I, 2), Slice(keyArray, 0)(I)
```