# How to display all the values of a variant using a message box in Visual Basic?

Tags: vba

I created a matrix within a Sub. I'd like to know, if there any fast way to plot the values of this matrix in a message box?

Here's the code:

```
Dim A() As Variant

ReDim A(5, 5)
   For i = 1 To 5
       For j = 1 To 5
        A(i, j) = 1
       Next j
 Next i
```

Trying to plot:

```
MsgBox A
```

How can I achieve this easily and fast? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What string representation do you want?  If you want a formatted "grid" then you would need to implement that yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The `MsgBox` function takes a `String` argument for its `Prompt` parameter. `A` is a 2D `Variant` array containing 25 `Variant/Integer` values and 11 `Variant/Empty` values - the implicit lower bound for implicitly-sized arrays is `0` unless you have `Option Base 1` specified; I'd recommend using explicit array bounds e.g. `ReDim A(1 To 5, 1 To 5)` instead, but that off-by-one error wasn't the question.

VBA doesn't know how you want to represent an array as a string. In .NET the default string representation of an `int` array looks like this: `int[]`, because the default `ToString` implementation simply yields the name of the object's data type: other languages might have other default string representations for an array, but the bottom line is, you need to implement that yourself.

Maybe you want it tab-delimited? Or comma-separated?

Easily? Iterate the array and concatenate your string:

```
Dim s As String
For i = LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1)
    For j = LBound(A, 2) To UBound(A, 2)
        s = s & vbTab & A(i, j)
    Next
    s = s & vbNewLine
Next
MsgBox s
```

Fast? Use a [StringBuilder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/67596/23788):

```
With New StringBuilder
    For i = LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1)
        For j = LBound(A, 2) To UBound(A, 2)
            .Append A(i, j) & vbTab
        Next
        .Append vbNewLine
    Next
    MsgBox .ToString
End With
```

Fancy? Take a [Slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175178/1188513) of each `i` element, use the `VBA.Strings.Join` function to make each "slice" into a delimited string (specify the separator you need), and append each delimited string to the final string representation.

Answer (score 1):

Make a string of your array and plot this, try:

```
Sub tst()
Dim A() As Variant
Dim aa As String

ReDim A(5, 5)
   For i = LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1)
       For j = LBound(A, 2) To UBound(A, 2)
        A(i, j) = 1
        aa = aa & A(i, j) & vbTab
       Next j
        aa = aa & vbCrLf
 Next i
MsgBox aa
End Sub
```